# contextPath appending issue in java script and JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

**Version :**

Apache MyFaces 2.1.14

Rich Faces 4.3.5

**Issue :**

I am observing very strange issue. Below is the code for java script.
The script automatically redirects the user to a url returned from back end code.

The issue is , the below java script code is not working consistently w.r.t contextPath. 
Thats is when `#{request.contextPath}` is appended at the start of the redirectUrl , it gives very erroneous url and redirection fails.
But above behavior is not consistent also , sometimes above set up works .
I have observed that below java script code is not giving consistent results for different browsers also w.r.t appending `#{request.contextPath}`
We are using JSF as a back end framework.

Can anybody point what is wrong in below java script code ? 
Is there any better practice of redirecting to the page using java script other han below code ?

Please help as I am really driving crazy for solving above issue.

**Code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function redirect(){                            
                var redirecUrl = "#{controller.bean.url}";              
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.replace(redirecUrl);
                 }, 4000); //4 secs delay
            }
            window.onload = function(){redirect();}

</script>
```

Comment: Give samples of what the output URLs look like

Comment: @kolossus: Thanks for your repply . It seems that legacy code getting invoked when controller.bean.url gets called was causing this issue. The url returned from controller.bean.url was not consistent causing this issue.  After fixing method controller.bean.url , this issue is not observed